# Select TOP x From table

Tags: sql, select

This is a rather unique problem and I don;t know if there is an answer. Im trying to input a variable amount of records to insert into a table depending on the value of another table. This is what I have tried

```
insert into TABLE1
select TOP cast((select Value from TABLE3 WHERE column_name = 'blah') as int) * from TABLE2
```

So im trying to get the value from table 3, and use that value to grab the top x records from table 2 to be inserted into table 1.

the error listed is Incorrect syntax near cast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP doesn't specify the database they are using, but SQL Server allows a variable.  try it out:

```
declare @YourTable table (RowID int identity(1,1), ColA char(4))
INSERT INTO @YourTable values ('a');INSERT INTO @YourTable values ('aa');INSERT INTO @YourTable values ('aaa');
INSERT INTO @YourTable values ('b');INSERT INTO @YourTable values ('bb');INSERT INTO @YourTable values ('bbb');
INSERT INTO @YourTable values ('c');INSERT INTO @YourTable values ('cc');INSERT INTO @YourTable values ('ccc');

declare @x int=5
select top (@x) * from @YourTable
```

output:

```
      RowID ColA
----------- ----
          1 a   
          2 aa  
          3 aaa 
          4 b   
          5 bb  

(5 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 3):

<s>TOP x cannot be specified in a variable.</s>It actually can, see KM's answer (which is definitely better than mine).

An option here would be a dynamic query

```
DECLARE @topx AS integer;
SET @topx = (select Value from TABLE3 WHERE column_name = 'blah')

DECLARE @query AS varchar(max);
SET @query = 'INSERT INTO table1 SELECT TOP ' + convert(varchar(10),@topx) 
              + ' FROM table2'

exec sp_executesql query
```

Comment: OP doesn't specify which database they are using, but SQL Server allows for a `TOP (@Variable)`, see my answer for a working example. **As a result, your SQL Server example code here is needlessly complex and unnecessary.**

Comment: @KM Nice, I was not aware of that. That means in OP's case just putting the whole `CAST` part into parentheses should make it work?

Comment: yes and expression will work, including a single column/row query.  I'm just not sure how many different databases support this other than SQL Server.

Comment: @TomasPastircak That was my thoughts. I tried it and it worked. Thats very interesting to know. I was expecting a complex answer like you gave as a work around but...win-win

Comment: @Calvin Smith, you only need to do it the simple way, like how I show in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a where clause on Row number to do the same thing. Something like

```
insert into TABLE1
select * from TABLE2 where row_number < cast((select Value from TABLE3 WHERE column_name = 'blah') as int)
```

Code has not been tested, just showing the idea.

Comment: @CalvinSmith what do you mean it will only work once

Comment: Your getting the row number as a variable. The row number could be 10000, and the result of the cast will be between 1-1000

Comment: @CalvinSmith row number is not a standard variable, it varies with different DBMS. It is a variable for telling you the number of rows the select statement has returned. Top 50 is equivalent to Row_Number <= 50

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to pass the value of N as a column name in `SELECT TOP(N)`  without using any variables or dynamic sql.

See below :

**TestData**

```
DECLARE @TABLE3 TABLE (VALUE INT) 
INSERT INTO @TABLE3 VALUES 
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)

DECLARE @TABLE2 TABLE (VALUE INT, OtherColumn INT) 
INSERT INTO @TABLE2 VALUES 
(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),
(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),
(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT T2.*
FROM @TABLE3 T3 CROSS APPLY 
                         (SELECT TOP (T3.Value) *
                          FROM @TABLE2
                          WHERE VALUE = T3.VALUE) T2
```

**Result Set**

```
╔═══════╦═════════════╗
║ VALUE ║ OtherColumn ║
╠═══════╬═════════════╣
║     1 ║           1 ║
║     2 ║           1 ║
║     2 ║           2 ║
║     3 ║           1 ║
║     3 ║           2 ║
║     3 ║           3 ║
╚═══════╩═════════════╝
```

**Query for your Data**

```
SELECT T2.*
FROM TABLE3 T3 CROSS APPLY 
                         (SELECT TOP (T3.Value) *
                          FROM TABLE2
                          WHERE SomeColumn = T3.SomeColumn
                          AND ColumnName = 'blah') T2
```